# Apache2 Client Certificate on a single VirtualHost

Tags: certificate, apache2

How can I enable in Apache2 to require a valid client certificate for only ONE virtual host out of 20?

Do i need to enable it globally and then just don't require it on the other 19?

Comment: What you mean when asking about `Client Certificate`?

Comment: SSL Client Certificate Authentication

Comment: just define it in that virtualhost, have you tried? what's the problem? The other options you mention are...odd.